# Getting an array of JSON sub-objects and the angular way of looking for a match in an array.

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

## Question 1

Assume I am getting a JSON object `scope.tagSet`, which is in the following format.

```
{ Tags : [
           {"TagID" : "ID1" , "TagName" : "Name1"},
           {"TagID" : "ID2" , "TagName" : "Name2"},
           {"TagID" : "ID3" , "TagName" : "Name3"}
         ]
}
```

Inside an angular directive I am making an array of all the values in `TagName` as follows.

```
for(var i= 0; i < scope.tagSet.Tags.length; i++){
                          scope.tagNames[i] = scope.tagSet.Tags[i].TagName;
}
```

Is looping through and assigning each the only option here? Or is there any other way which is more efficient.

## Question 2

Say that I've got the array `tagNames[]` My next job is to perform a search to check if a given variable `varString` exists in the array `tagNames[]` and return true or false accordingly. 
I know that `scope.tagNames.indexOf(varString)` will return `-1` when there are no matches,

but is it the angular way? Are these approaches considered good practice?

Comment: I think the biggest "non-angular"-thing is, that your `tagNames` won't reflect changes in `tagSet` unless you take special care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is make a lookuplist. In javascript you can use the object:

```
function arrayToLookup(a, key) {
    var o = {};
    for (var i = a.length; i--;) {
        o[a[i][key]] = true;
    }
    return o;
}
```

Use it like this

```
var lookupList = arrayToLookup(scope.tagSet.Tags, "TagName");
```

now you can check if it is available by doing this:

```
lookupList["Name1"];//returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you so keen to do it the angular way? What if you one day decide to dump angular? That's more likely than keeping angular but dumping JS. This is the JS way:

```
scope.tagNames = scope.tagSet.Tags.map( function (i) {return i.TagName;} )
```

Then use indexOf as you suggested at the outset.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var arrayNew=[];
    angular.forEach(scope.tagSet.Tags, function(value, key) {
       arrayNew[i] = value.TagName;
    });
scope.tagNames=arrayNew;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `angular-filter`[module](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#contains) to check if your array contains the given item:

```
$scope.items = [
    {"TagID" : "ID1" , "TagName" : "Name1"},
    {"TagID" : "ID2" , "TagName" : "Name2"},
    {"TagID" : "ID3" , "TagName" : "Name3"}
]

// returns true
$scope.Name1 = $filter('contains')($scope.items,'TagName == "Name1"');
// returns false
$scope.Name4 = $filter('contains')($scope.items,'TagName == "Name4"');
```

Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AmAtHmmKSTR2JdwyeE6p?p=preview)